# Round before convert to string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have problem in rounding, this is seems so common, but I can't find the answer by googling, so I decide to ask it here.

Here's my data

```
        day         reg     log ad      trans   paid
1111    20171005    172     65  39.0    14.0    3.0
1112    20171006    211     90  46.0    17.0    4.0
1113    20171007    155     70  50.0    17.0    1.0
1114    20171008    174     71  42.0    18.0    0.0
1115    20171009    209     63  43.0    21.0    2.0
```

Here's what I did, I still want to `%` in number

```
table['% log'] = (table.log / table.reg * 100).astype(str) + '%'
table['% ad'] = (table.ad / table.reg * 100).astype(str) + '%'
table['% trans'] = (table.trans / table.reg* 100).astype(str) + '%'
table['% paid'] = (table.paid / table.reg * 100).astype(str) + '%'
```

Here's what I get, need a final touch in rounding

```
        day         reg     log ad      trans   paid    % log            % ad       % trans     % paid
1111    20171005    172     65  39.0    14.0    3.0     37.7906976744%  22.6744186047%  8.13953488372%  1.74418604651%
1112    20171006    211     90  46.0    17.0    4.0     42.654028436%   21.8009478673%  8.05687203791%  1.89573459716%
1113    20171007    155     70  50.0    17.0    1.0     45.1612903226%  32.2580645161%  10.9677419355%  0.645161290323%
1114    20171008    174     71  42.0    18.0    0.0     40.8045977011%  24.1379310345%  10.3448275862%  0.0%
1115    20171009    209     63  43.0    21.0    2.0     30.1435406699%  20.5741626794%  10.04784689%    0.956937799043%
```

What I want is the percentage is not too long, just round in two digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
table['% log'] = (table.log / table.reg * 100).round(2).astype(str) + '%'
```

Better solution is select all columns by subset and output `join` to original `df`:

```
cols = ['log','ad','trans','paid']
table =(table.join(table[cols].div(table.reg, 0)
                              .mul(100)
                              .round(2)
                              .astype(str)
                              .add('%')
                              .add_prefix('%% ')))
print (table)
           day  reg  log    ad  trans  paid   % log    % ad % trans % paid
1111  20171005  172   65  39.0   14.0   3.0  37.79%  22.67%   8.14%  1.74%
1112  20171006  211   90  46.0   17.0   4.0  42.65%   21.8%   8.06%   1.9%
1113  20171007  155   70  50.0   17.0   1.0  45.16%  32.26%  10.97%  0.65%
1114  20171008  174   71  42.0   18.0   0.0   40.8%  24.14%  10.34%   0.0%
1115  20171009  209   63  43.0   21.0   2.0  30.14%  20.57%  10.05%  0.96%
```

Also if need nicer output - add `0` for 2 decimals:

```
table =(table.join(table[cols].div(table.reg, 0)
                              .mul(100)
                              .applymap("{0:.2f}".format)
                              .add('%')
                              .add_prefix('%% ')))
print (table)
           day  reg  log    ad  trans  paid   % log    % ad % trans % paid
1111  20171005  172   65  39.0   14.0   3.0  37.79%  22.67%   8.14%  1.74%
1112  20171006  211   90  46.0   17.0   4.0  42.65%  21.80%   8.06%  1.90%
1113  20171007  155   70  50.0   17.0   1.0  45.16%  32.26%  10.97%  0.65%
1114  20171008  174   71  42.0   18.0   0.0  40.80%  24.14%  10.34%  0.00%
1115  20171009  209   63  43.0   21.0   2.0  30.14%  20.57%  10.05%  0.96%
```

Comment: Oh, it is that easy